# Closing the ui-bootstrap tab changes the ui-router state to default state - happens after upgrade ui-bootstrap to 0.12.0

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-router

The issue is, If i close the tab, the state(ui-router) changes to the default state. It is hard to explain the problem, so i created the simple plunker @

http://plnkr.co/edit/Yigj4VR10zTAMG9DQo6C?p=preview

If you close any of the tab in the settings page then you are taken to the home page. I expect to stay on the settings page with the first tab being selected after closing the tab.

If you comment the 0.12.0 version in the plunker and un comment 0.11.0 version, then the application works as expected.

I think the issue is to do with the fix for the following bug -

```
https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/pull/2763 (or) `https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2155`
```

There is no error message printed on the console so it is hard to identify the issue by myself.

Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Plunker doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: Plunker is back to normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is finally resolved after upgrading to angular 1.3.15. Please see the comment on [git hub](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/3073#issuecomment-92693193).